# Derby Timestamp Comparison

Tags: java, sql, date, timestamp

Currently I work with an Apache Derby database and there I have a problem. 
There is a column that has datatype TIMESTAMP. Now with Java I access to this column, but I want just find records with a certain date.

For example, the entries in column colTime:

- 2013-08-14 18:20:00.0
- 2013-08-15 18:20:00.0
- 2013-08-15 18:21:00.0
- 2013-08-16 18:20:00.0

And now I want to find all entries with date 2013-08-15.

I don't know, should my SQL query look like this? I didn't think so..

```
st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE DATE(colTime)=DATE(TIMESTAMP("
    + new Timestamp(time.getTimeInMillis()) + ")");
```

Comment: I wrote "solved" in header. Or there is another way to show this state?

Comment: @salted yes, add an answer to this question and click the check mark to accept it.

Answer (score 3):

[According to the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18237293/3), the solution was:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE DATE(colTime) = DATE(TIMESTAMP(/*timestamp*/))
```